# Why are the ducts of pancreas lined with compound epithelium?

Tags: anatomy

Most other places with compound epithelium are in contact with the outside world, and that of course makes sense. So why would a duct snugly placed inside our body need stratified epithelium? Is it to protect against the protein digesting enzymes passing by?

edit- i still havent found a satisfactory answer...

Comment: Do not bump your post with trivial edits. You can always edit to include new background you find even if it doesn't answer your original question.